# Reference to single cell array in a merged cell

Tags: excel

I am working on a list of employees with multiple sheets, and need all the sheets to collect the names from the ADMIN sheet. This is to enable management to delete a record on the admin page, and the other sheets to automatically remove the record as well. The LEAVE sheet, needs to have the names in a merged cell as indicated.

[image]

[image]

If I reference them one by one, I get a #REF! when a cell is deleted in ADMIN, and the formulas in the rest of the table gets mixed. If I do it by dragging down, the formula identifies the merged cell as 3 rows (understandable), but I need a way to change that. It needs to be treated as one row. Please help with any way to do that, or another solution to display the given information.

Comment: In case of deleting row or cell will cause `#REF!` error. You have to avoid deleting rather you can maintain status for employees like `Active/Inactive`.

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX and some MATH:

```
=INDEX(Admin!A:A,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)/3+2)
```

The `3` is the number of rows per merged cell.  The `1` is the start row of the list on `Admin`.  Adjust accordingly.  The `$ZZ1` reference is just a counter and does not matter what column as we only care about it starting in row 1.

Now as the rows in Admin are deleted it will not return ref and the names will move up accordingly.

before deletion:

[image]

After deleting `Name2` on the Admin Sheet:

[image]